# Angular Customer directive , for change of color of link <a> on hover

Tags: angular, angular-directive, directive

I need a help in implementing this use case .
How can I write code for customer directive in angular to change of link  on hover over.

Can we use ElementRef for this?
Any leads, Please!

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Any suggestions or approach I can try ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Why not use css?